# Login form not submitting

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

I am creating a login form for my java app. But I can't get it to submit. I can't find any errors in my form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Log in</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="container">
 <div id="top">
    <h1>Please complete the form below</h1>
  </div>
 <div id="leftSide">
 <fieldset>
 <legend>Login details</legend>
<form action="login.jsp" method="get" class="form">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<div class="div_texbox">
<input name="username" type="text" class="username" id="username" value="username" />
</div>
 <label for="password">Password</label>
<div class="div_texbox">
<input name="password" type="password" class="password" id="password" value="password" />
</div>
<div class="button_div">
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" class="buttons" />
</div>
 </form>
 </fieldset>
 </div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

There are some  from other parts of page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submit button type should be submit.

Answer (score 3):

change this:

```
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" class="buttons" />
```

to this:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="buttons" />
```

Answer (score 2):

change the input type from button to Submit in this line and you  should be able to submit

```
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" class="buttons" />
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is normal, if you can't submit it take a look to your "login.jsp".
also you can use

```
<form action="login.jsp" method="post" class="form">
```

and change:

```
type="botton"
```

to

```
type="submit"
```